# Link is taking / in the begining by default in ReactJs How to remove it?

Tags: reactjs

See the "/" thing is coming in href before my url  by default, How to remove it ?

** For Video only its taking / in the begning

```
<Link to ={this.state.videourl} className="videopopup">

<a class="video-popup" href="/localhost/site/video.mp4">
```

Comment: If you remove the `/` then the url will not be what you expect after clicking on a tag.

Comment: @maya_nk99 this is coming by default, i want this url href="localhost/site/video.mp4"
if i use <a> tag then its not taking / at the beginning, but now m using Link So its taking / in the begining of href, which i dont want